# Find points within cutoff distance of other points with scipy

Tags: python, scipy, distance

Let's say I have two sets of points:

```
>>> points1.shape
(10000, 3)
>>> points2.shape
(1529, 3)
```

And I want a list of indices of `points1` within a euclidean distance `cutoff` of a point in `points2`. I could easily do this using `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` like so:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy

indices = numpy.argwhere(cdist(points1, points2).min(axis=0) < cutoff)
```

However this seems inefficient since I don't need to know how far away points are from each other, just whether they're within a cutoff distance. Could a KDTree help with this?

Comment: If two points in `points1` are both within `cutoff` of the same point in `points2`, do you want the index of both points, or just the closer one?

Comment: I'd like the index of both points - I'm taking a large pointcloud and a small pointcloud and deleting the volume around the small pointcloud from the large pointcloud.

Comment: Trees would help. I've not done KD trees (only quad/octrees), but if you are not adding to the list, give KD ones a shot. With the 2nd idea muraveill suggested, that sped up my code to 200%, which was still slow. I added trees to work alongside that and the overall speed increase was like 2000% for 8000 points (and exponentially better for more points), so definitely worth the effort. It's probably not really relevant but here's the post I did with the code - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118299/n-dimensional-maze-generation-with-octrees-and-pathfinding

Answer (score 2):

Here are 3 alternatives, one using cdist, two using [scipy.spatial.cKDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html):

```
import itertools as IT
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial as spatial
import scipy.spatial.distance as dist
np.random.seed(2016)
points1 = np.random.randint(100, size=(10**5, 3))
points2 = np.random.randint(100, size=(1529, 3))
cutoff = 5

def using_cdist(points1, points2, cutoff):
    indices = np.where(dist.cdist(points1, points2) <= cutoff)[0]
    indices = np.unique(indices)
    return indices

def using_kdtree(points1, points2, cutoff):
    # build the KDTree using the *smaller* points array
    tree = spatial.cKDTree(points2)
    groups = tree.query_ball_point(points1, cutoff)
    indices = np.unique([i for i, grp in enumerate(groups) if len(grp)])
    return indices

def using_kdtree2(points1, points2, cutoff):
    # build the KDTree using the *larger* points array
    tree = spatial.cKDTree(points1)
    groups = tree.query_ball_point(points2, cutoff)
    indices = np.unique(IT.chain.from_iterable(groups))
    return indices

cdist_result = using_cdist(points1, points2, cutoff)
kdtree_result = using_kdtree(points1, points2, cutoff)
kdtree_result2 = using_kdtree2(points1, points2, cutoff)
assert np.allclose(cdist_result, kdtree_result)
assert np.allclose(cdist_result, kdtree_result2)
```

Of these 3 alternatives, `using_kdtree2` is the fastest:

```
In [80]: %timeit using_kdtree3(points1, points2, cutoff)
10 loops, best of 3: 92.4 ms per loop

In [103]: %timeit using_kdtree(points1, points2, cutoff)
1 loops, best of 3: 938 ms per loop

In [104]: %timeit using_cdist(points1, points2, cutoff)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.51 s per loop
```

My intuition about what would be fastest turned out to be entirely wrong. I
thought building the KDTree using the smaller points array would be
fastest. Even though building the KDTree using the bigger points array is
somewhat slower, calling `tree.query_ball_point` on the smaller points array is
much quicker:

```
In [68]: %timeit tree = spatial.cKDTree(points2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 312 µs per loop

In [69]: %timeit tree = spatial.cKDTree(points1)
10 loops, best of 3: 45.7 ms per loop

In [66]: %timeit tree = spatial.cKDTree(points2); groups = tree.query_ball_point(points1, cutoff)
1 loops, best of 3: 933 ms per loop

In [67]: %timeit tree = spatial.cKDTree(points1); groups = tree.query_ball_point(points2, cutoff)
10 loops, best of 3: 89.3 ms per loop
```

---

Note that there are some problems with using

```
def orig(points1, points2, cutoff):
    return np.argwhere(dist.cdist(points1, points2).min(axis=0) < cutoff)
```

First, by calling `min(axis=0)` you lose information if two points in `points1`
are both within `cutoff` of a point in `points2`. You would only get the index
of the closest point. The other problem is that by calling `min` over the
0-axis, all that remains is the 1-axis which is associated with `points2`. So
`orig` is returning indices into `points2`, not `points1`.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas (?):

- If you don't need to know the distance, you can save the computation of the square root by comparing the square of the distance to the square of the threshold (`cdist` will compute the square root).
- A first pass to exclude points which x coordinate is already further than the threshold, then the same with y and z, would save some computation. Especially since 'or' is lazy in Python (if x is already far enough, it wouldn't even check for y).